# Using XP, can't access other shared folders in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, networking, file-sharing

I have two shared folders in Windows 7 with exactly the same sharing/security settings however I can only access one from XP e.g., `FolderA`. The other folder `FolderB` can't be seen by XP. Any ideas why?

**Additional Info:**

When using Guest account in XP, I can see `FolderA` but not `FolderB`

When using Admin account in XP, I cannot see both folders

BTW I can ping both the IP/Computer name, XP to W7 and vice versa.

I also can't see workgroup computers in XP, but I can see both XP and W7 in W7's workgroup (i.e., `View network computers and devices`)

Comment: down voter, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: what happens if you turn on/off simple file sharing?

Comment: @Logman nothing really happens, no error.

Comment: @Logman BTW I also can't see workgroup computers in XP, but I can see both XP and W7 in W7's `View network computers and devices`

Comment: What are the settings under Advanced Sharing Settings for the Home or Work and Public profile Win7.... Network Discovery? Turn on File Print Sharing? Public Folder sharing? "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings"

Comment: @Logman Here you go http://i.imgur.com/U3cUS.png

Comment: Are you really sure the security settings are the same for both folder? It looks the account on Windows XP does not have permissions to access the other folder. The levels of permissions are applied on W7 side: the share permissions and security permissions of the shared folder. Take a look at audit log on Win7, it may have some denial records. And it would be better if both computers use the same workgroup (it's more of an issue for XP than Win7).

Answer (score 0):

It works.

You should verify that you can ping computer (xp) ping computer Win7 and vice versa

Make sure you can access a shared folder on WIN7 using UNC notation. Create two folders on Win7 and make them shared by the network users.

On windows xp create mapped drives for the two folders. Now you can see the two folders.